# Output the help message manually with JewelCLI?

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

I have implemented a small command line interface using [JewelCLI](http://jewelcli.lexicalscope.com/) and it creates an automatic help/usage message, but I can't find any way to output it manually when needed. The reason I have is that I want to take some non-option parameters (file names) that are mandatory and it would be nice to use the same message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`Cli.getHelpMessage()`](http://jewelcli.lexicalscope.com/apidocs/uk/co/flamingpenguin/jewel/cli/Cli.html#getHelpMessage%28%29) method; if you're using a `CliFactory` you can get one via the [`createCli()` method](http://jewelcli.lexicalscope.com/apidocs/uk/co/flamingpenguin/jewel/cli/CliFactory.html#createCli%28java.lang.Class%29).

Comment: Ah, I can use `createCli`instead of `parseArguments` directly, thanks!

I am using @Unparsed, but there isn't any way that I can see to put any constraints on that using the interface, so I'm checking the result manually.

Comment: @Stoffe For the help message, yep :) Yep, I mixed up two different things with the `@Unparsed`; realized that later.

Comment: :) I opened an [issue](https://github.com/lexicalscope/jewelcli/issues/1) in the project, I think it could be useful. Again, thanks!

Comment: @Stoffe I agree--seems kind of obvious, too, that you might want to enforce the presence of an un-named list of things like files or whatever. Maybe we're just not seeing it. Sure don't see it, though.

Comment: Sorry, this thing with the unparsed options always being allowed was a bug, it should be fixed in the latest release (in maven it is at com.lexicalscope.jewelcli:jewelcli:0.7.6) - please let me know if there are any further problems with it.